# Checking if a column is not null or empty

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a better way to do the following to check if a column is not empty/null?

```
(v.file_name is not null and v.file_name != '' 
 and v.file_last_known_location is not null and v.file_last_known_location != '')
```

Comment: length(trim(filename)) > 0 maybe?

Comment: If your fields are properly indexed, I think your posted solution will outperform the use of functions such as `coalesce` which negate the indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is clearer

```
COALESCE(v.file_name,'') != '' AND COALESCE(v.file_last_known_location,'') != ''
```

On some systems this may perform worse (as @sgeddes notes) against indexed columns.

Answer (score 1):

I would say even though the current query looks clumsy, it will out perform the suggested answer when you have index on `file_name` and `file_last_known_location`.

The usage of `function` in `Where` clause will restrict optimizer from using `Index`. So better to use original query

```
(v.file_name is not null and v.file_name != '' 
 and v.file_last_known_location is not null and v.file_last_known_location != '')
```